Ubuntu 22.04 4K resolution low FPS / stuttering
I have set up Ubuntu 22.04 in Dual boot with Windows 11. I also have RTX3060 Laptop GPU. I'm using X11.
I recently bought a 4K monitor that works perfectly on Windows. When I use it on Ubuntu, I see annoying stuttering, especially when scrolling.
The issue doesn't happen at 2K or FHD. The issue doesn't happen on the internal monitor.
I tried different nvidia drivers and it's the same issue. My current nvidia driver is 550. Here is the output of nvidia-smi:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.120                Driver Version: 550.120        CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P8             15W /   80W |    1222MiB /   6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2409      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            690MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2650      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          136MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4456      G   ...seed-version=20241121-182614.093000        378MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7155      G   nvidia-settings                                 0MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7304      G   /snap/okular/159/usr/bin/okular                 2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


I tried Nvidia Performance mode from PRIME Profiles but it's the same issue.
This post has the same issue, except the all the proposed solutions didn't work with me.
