Wayland on 4k monitor set at 60 Hz feels like 30 Hz
I use Ubuntu 24.04 with a 4k monitor. On X11, I set 60 Hz and I get 60 FPS when testing using the UFO Test website.
When I try Wayland, the settings say it's set at 60 Hz as welll, but it's no way 60 Hz, and when I test it using UFO Test, it shows only 30 FPS.
I have nvidia-driver-550. I tested the PPA with nvidia-driver-560 driver, but I still have the same issue.
What could be the reason?

I suppose that you use a laptop and you connect your monitor through HDMI. If that's indeed the case, then the problem is that NVIDIA doesn't yet support Wayland (or the other way around) 100%. So using Wayland with NVIDIA cards presents laggy behavior and lower FPS than what you set in the Display settings.
I also have the same issue and haven't yet found a solution (because there isn't another one) other than using Xorg instead of Wayland. The issue will be likely solved when NVIDIA decides to improve their Linux driver and fully support Wayland. Until then, Xorg is your (our) friend.
Below are some relevant posts I have found about the matter, none containing a solution but indicating that there is none yet, unfortunately:

Nvidia, please get it together with external monitors on Wayland
565 Drivers on Debian 12 - Wayland>Low FPS vs. Xorg> High FPS
Poor performance in Nvidia Wayland sessions 
Low performance in Wayland sessions with dual GPUs (Nvidia discrete) and dual monitors
KDE and Nvidia drivers causing Low FPS/Lag/Stuttering
Wayland performance is noticably worse than x11/xorg 


The problem with Xorg in my case is that I have stuttering especially during scrolling. I described the issue here if you have any solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1533677/ubuntu-22-04-4k-resolution-low-fps-stuttering

It would be helpful if you could add a video in your question, showcasing the stuttering you mention. I have also observed some tearing from time to time on Xorg (not sure if that's what you mean by stuttering), usually when I get a graphics card driver update. This tearing goes away when I remove and reinstall the driver. Try that and see if it works for you too. Other than that, I don't think I could be of much help.
